# jQuery show up results after a very long time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.12.4 (because I have to be compatible with IE8 and above) and this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pagesUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&origin=*&list=categorymembers&indexpageids=1&cmtitle=Category%3AEnglish-language+film+directors&cmtype=page&cmlimit=50";
    var randomTitles = [];
    $.getJSON(pagesUrl, function(data){
        var pages = data.query.categorymembers;
        for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            do{
                var index = Math.round(Math.random()*49);
            }while(randomTitles.indexOf(pages[index].title) != -1);
            randomTitles[pages[index].pageid] = pages[index].title;
        }
        console.log(randomTitles);
    });
});
```

It should receive a JSON file from Wikipedia in which there are information about 50 pages in a category. The it selected 20 random pages and fill the associative array with *Wikipedia page id*:*Wikipedia page title* pairs.

It does its job but the results are shown only after, maybe, 10 seconds.
Anyone can explain me, firstly, why and, then, how to fix this?
Thanks, I'm very new to jQuery world.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint and walk through the code to see if anything is taking longer than excepted. Using the browsers developer tools.

Comment: Look at the Network tab in DevTools to see how long Wikipedia is taking to answer the request. If it's taking 10 seconds, the problem isn't in your code, it's at their end. Maybe try requesting a smaller number of pages. If you're sending them lots of requests, they might have a rate limiter.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Lance your looping is inefficient and becomes slower the more iterations of your loop you go through. Another change I made was to change your randomTitles from an array to an object which stops your array from becoming as large as the largest ID in the result from Wikipedia.

```js
 var pagesUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&origin=*&list=categorymembers&indexpageids=1&cmtitle=Category%3AEnglish-language+film+directors&cmtype=page&cmlimit=50";
    var randomTitles = {};
    $.getJSON(pagesUrl, function(data){
        var pages = data.query.categorymembers;
        for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            var index = Math.floor((Math.random() * (50 - i)));
            randomTitles[pages[index].pageid] = pages[index].title;
            pages.slice(index, index + 1)
        }
        console.log(randomTitles);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes so long because you're looping an enormous number of times (that number of times being defined as however high your page IDs go and however far apart their IDs are from each other). The following code adjusts your original slightly and pulls down the 50 pages, then randomly grabs 20 of them in only 20 iterations, so is obviously much faster.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pagesUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&origin=*&list=categorymembers&indexpageids=1&cmtitle=Category%3AEnglish-language+film+directors&cmtype=page&cmlimit=50";
    var randomTitles = [];
    $.getJSON(pagesUrl, function(data){
        var pages = data.query.categorymembers;
        for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            var page = pages.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * pages.length), 1)[0]
            randomTitles[page.pageid] = page.title
        }
        console.log(randomTitles);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By through console, I observed your randomTitles:

```
(53029416) [undefined × 32901, "Woody Allen", undefined × 29907, "Warren Beatty", undefined × 29543,  ...]
```

Those `undefined*32901` is caused by `randomTitles[pages[index].pageid]`, it created huge amount of `undefined` items in your randomTitles array once `"pageid": 419280` jumped a large gap.

To fix the issue, you can change it to:

```
randomTitles[i] = pages[index].title;
```